# Converting a list of lists from string to integer without map method

Tags: python, list, matrix, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert the following list from string to int:

```
field = [['0', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
         ['0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '0'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '0'],
         ['0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
         ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1']]
```

So far I only found and tried the following code:

```
for i in field:
    field = list(map(int, i))
```

Which when printed returns this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1]
```

Aside from not returning what I wanted, I don't feel comfortable using the `list` or `map` methods because I don't know what exactly they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `list` comprehension with another `list` comprehension:

```
field = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in field]
```

Or use `map` with a `list` comprehension:

```
field = [list(map(int, x)) for x in field]
```

And now after both codes, you add:

```
print(field)
```

It will output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1]]
```

Comment: field = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in field] is what i wanted

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the desired result is to do a two for loops, doing a cast to integer.

```
for l in field:
    for internal_element in l:
        print(int(internal_element))
```

After loop through items you should [cast to integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).